# How to make parent element span 50% of child height

Tags: css, height

Can a parent div be configured to span 50% of its child's height? The child height is variable so no static pixel values are possible.

I guess the parent can never be relative to the child, so something would need to be done to the child to make it only occupy 50% of its own height, so the parent considers the child to be smaller than it its contents, such as something like a negative margin.

Here is my test case codepen https://codepen.io/Frique/pen/zYjWOOL

```
.parent {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  /* height: 150px; This would work in this example but the real child element has variable height. */
}
.child {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do with this? share your real use case

Comment: The usecase is that the child is scaled down with transform: scale. CSS scale does not effect the document flow, so there is whitespace around the child. I'm wondering if we can decrease the size of the parent proportionally to match the scaled child and make it fit snuggly in place.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a pseudo element? Seems like you have no real need od the containing element at all. The parent will always grow, as it contains the child element, a box within in a box.

```
.child::before {
  background-color: blue;
  content: '';
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's not about visually seeing a colored box with half the size of .child, but about the document flow considering this parent to half of its real height. So in the example the .sibling element should appear higher up, which is what you see when you uncomment the `height: 150px;` on the parent.